# Can I put a PCI-E 3.0 x16 gpu in a PCI-E 1.0 x16 slot?

Tags: gpu, pci-e

I have an old motherboard the [Asus P5K Deluxe](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_775/P5K_DeluxeWiFiAP/#specifications). I need to change my current GPU ( NVIDIA 8800 GTX ) but all new GPU's seem to use a PCI-E 3.0 slot. Are the 3.0 backwards-compatible with the 1.0 slots? Are there any adapters? I have been googling this for some time now and I can't find something...

Thank you

Comment: Maybe try http://superuser.com/

Comment: Ok sorry, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PCIE 3.0 cards are backwards compatible with the 1.0 and the 2.0 slots, but you won't be able to enjoy the full extent of your new PCIE card. It will be restricted to Gen 1 speed (2.5 Gt/sec) while Gen 3 allows 8 Gt/sec and a better encoding scheme which actually makes it about X4 times faster.